# Fetch rows when fields in different tables do not match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in MS SQL Server: `Account` and `AccountStaging`.

Both tables have fields as `AccountNum`, `Consultant` and `Executive`.

My requirement is to fetch the rows from the `AccountStaging` table when the `Consultant` or `Executive` values do not match between `AccountStaging`and `Account`. The `AccountNum` has to match.

I tried the below query and it does not work.

```
SELECT ACS.AccountNum, ACS.Consultant, ACS.Executive
FROM AccountStaging ACS, Account ACC
WHERE ACS.AccountNum = ACC.AccountNum 
AND (
    (ACS.Consultant <> ACC.Consultant)
    OR
    (ACS.Executive <> ACC.Executive)
)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: @RadimBača, I am not sure. The resultset is empty and I guess It could be due to the null values.

Comment: And running `SELECT ACS.AccountNum, ACS.Consultant, ACS.Executive, ACC.Consultant, ACC.Executive
FROM AccountStaging ACS JOIN Account ACC
ON ACS.AccountNum = ACC.AccountNum` returns values with `NULL` values?

Comment: Yes, it appears that where ever the value is null on the AccountStaging table. And for the account 000000015235, both consultant and executive fields have values (not null) in both tables.

Comment: try `(
(ACS.Consultant != ACC.Consultant)
OR
(ACS.Executive != ACC.Executive)
)`

Comment: you probably need to show your sample data, your result using your query and your expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` on *matching* fields, and then test for no match:

```
SELECT ACS.AccountNum, ACS.Consultant, ACS.Executive
FROM AccountStaging ACS LEFT JOIN
     Account ACC
     ON ACS.AccountNum = ACC.AccountNum AND
        ACS.Consultant = ACC.Consultant AND
        ACS.Executive = ACC.Executive
WHERE ACC.AccountNum IS NULL;
```

Comment: As per OP: *The AccountNum **has to match***.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thanks for your response. However, the AccountNum has to match. So, I don't think a LEFT JOIN will work.

Comment: @Eric, I have tried the query and it did not work. For an account number 000000015235, the consultant name and the executive name are exactly same in both AccountStaging and Account tables. When I run the query, I don't want to see this record in the resultset. However, the resultset contains this record also.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli From the query, it is impossible to get records that has the same consultant and executive.  There must be spaces character in one of the fields.  Try to output the `LENGTH` of each field.